Create list column out of column names
I have a simple pl.DataFrame with a number of columns that only contain boolean values.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"s1": [True, True, False], "s2": [False, True, True], "s3": [False, False, False]}
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ s1    ┆ s2    ┆ s3    │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false │
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ false │
│ false ┆ true  ┆ false │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘

I need to add another column that contains lists of varying length. A list in any individual row should contain the column name where the values of the columns S1, s2, and s3 have a True value.
Here's what I am actually looking for:
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ s1    ┆ s2    ┆ s3    │ list         │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │ ---          │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  │ list[str]    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡══════════════╡
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false │ ["s1"]       │
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ false │ ["s1", "s2"] │
│ false ┆ true  ┆ false │ ["s2"]       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘


List API
You could build a list of when/then expressions and then remove the nulls.
df.with_columns(
   pl.concat_list(
      pl.when(col).then(pl.lit(col)) for col in df.columns
   )
   .list.drop_nulls()
   .alias("list")
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ s1    ┆ s2    ┆ s3    ┆ list         │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ list[str]    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false ┆ ["s1"]       │
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s1", "s2"] │
│ false ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s2"]       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘

Unpivot
If "raw performance" is of concern, it can be done at the frame level.
You can reshape with .unpivot() and .group_by to create the lists.
(df.with_row_index()
   .unpivot(index="index")
   .filter(pl.col.value) 
   .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(pl.col.variable.alias("list"))
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬──────────────┐
│ index ┆ list         │
│ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ u32   ┆ list[str]    │
╞═══════╪══════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ ["s1"]       │
│ 1     ┆ ["s1", "s2"] │
│ 2     ┆ ["s2"]       │
└───────┴──────────────┘

As we've maintained the order, we can horizontally .concat() to combine them.
pl.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.with_row_index()
          .unpivot(index="index")
          .filter(pl.col.value)
          .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
          .agg(pl.col.variable.alias("list"))
          .drop("index") # optional
    ], 
    how = "horizontal"
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ s1    ┆ s2    ┆ s3    ┆ list         │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ list[str]    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false ┆ ["s1"]       │
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s1", "s2"] │
│ false ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s2"]       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘

Timing
As a basic comparison.
bigger_df = df.sample(2_000_000, with_replacement=True)




Name
Time




concat_list
1.4s


unpivot + concat
0.2s




It's a bit tough to choose an accepted answer as all answers are leading to the expected result. Having said that, I think the when/then solution is quite intuitive. Thanks.

First You can create struct of all columns using struct, then you can use map_elements to apply a lambda func for each row.
The lambda func creates a list comprehension that includes the column name col if its corresponding value val is True. Then use alias for the new column as list.
desired_output = df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(df.columns)
    .map_elements(lambda x: [col for col, val in x.items() if val])
    .alias("list")
)


Alternatively you can do this
result = (
    df.with_columns(
        pl.concat_list(
            pl.when(pl.col(col)).then(pl.lit(col)).otherwise(pl.lit(None))
            for col in df.columns
        ).alias("temp_list")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("temp_list")
        .list.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_not_null()))
        .alias("list")
    )
    .drop("temp_list")
)


print(desired_output)
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ s1    ┆ s2    ┆ s3    ┆ list         │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ list[str]    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false ┆ ["s1"]       │
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s1", "s2"] │
│ false ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s2"]       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘


You could unpivot, filter, group_by.agg, and join:
(df.with_row_index()
   .join(df.with_row_index().unpivot(index='index').filter(pl.col('value'))
           .group_by('index').agg(pl.col('variable')),
         on='index', how='left'
        )
)

Output:
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ index ┆ s1    ┆ s2    ┆ s3    ┆ variable     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ u32   ┆ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ list[str]    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ false ┆ ["s1"]       │
│ 1     ┆ true  ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s1", "s2"] │
│ 2     ┆ false ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ ["s2"]       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘

